# Image icon within Toast maketext message

Tags: android, toast, android-toast

I am beginning learning some android mobile development and have created a notepad app through some tutorials and am now wanting to customise it a little.

I currently have a Toast maketext message that displays when a user saves a new note. The code is as follows:

```
if(Utilities.saveNote(this, new Note(mNoteCreationTime, title, content))) 
Toast.makeText(this, "Swag Note has been saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

What I am wanting to do is add a small icon at both ends of this toast message.

Is there a relatively simple way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toasts cannot have icons. You can create a custom Toast with `ImageView`s in it ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16789027/7625902)). However, there might be an unicode symbol that suits your purpose: in that case, you can just paste it.

**Edit:**

To make the linked example work, you'd just have to add a View for the image with id "toast_image", which will be invoked this way:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_image);
```

Show Toast as you do it now:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Swag Note has been saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Show MyToast from linked example:

```
MyToast.show(this, "Swag Note has been saved", false);
```

Comment: How would I go about actually implementing this? As in, how would I adapt my current code to suit your example? Where are you actually defining the text of the TextView?

Comment: Are you able to help with this?

Comment: @Standingbear123 I've added some instructions.

Comment: Thanks so much for this @wordbug! It worked great and I was able to implement exactly what I wanted.